# How to enable ipv6 connections for MySql in Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, zipkin

I'm running openzipkin in Azure (docker image) and I'm getting this error for the past two weeks out of the blue.

Nothing has changed in the code because I'm using a specific docker tag. Seems like Azure has internally changed something with MySql recently?

I don't see any options under `Server parameters` to enable ipv6 AND you cannot add an ipv6 firewall rule because it only allows ipv4 to be entered.

```
Could not connect: Server is not configured to allow ipv6 connections.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2019/01/02/lesson-learned-52-azure-database-for-mysql-server-is-not-configured-to-allow-ipv6-connections/ that recommends adding VNet rules to the MySQL connection security. This however does not work for Basic tier.

Solution:
Somehow an Azure MySQL cannot communicate with a VM in the same region.

To fix this - Remove Microsoft.Sql endpoint in

```
Virtual network > yourResourceGroup > Service endpoints
```